# Workbook.Open can not find the file

Tags: excel, vba

I am running the following code. The code is for finding some particular values in all the Excel sheets in a folder.

It gives me the error

> "Sorry, we couldn't find the file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

when it executes

```
Set wbSlave = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myfilname)
```

Please help.

```
Sub find_cells()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim cell_content As String
    Dim total_values As Long
    Dim cell_location As Range
    Dim cell_address As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim myfilname As String
    Dim fldrpath As String
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim wbSlave As Workbook
    Dim currentfilename As String
    
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook
    j = 3
    total_values = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wbMaster.Sheets("Engine").Range("A:A")) 
    fldrpath = "C:\test\" 
    myfilname = Dir(fldrpath & "*.xls*")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While myfilname <> ""
        'myfilname = Dir()
        Set wbSlave = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myfilname)
    
            For Each sht In wbSlave.Sheets
                For i = 2 To total_values
                    cell_content = wbMaster.Sheets("Engine").Range("A" & i).Value
                        With sht.UsedRange
                            Set cell_location = .Find(cell_content, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                    
                                If Not cell_location Is Nothing Then               
                                    cell_address = cell_location.Address
    
                                        Do              
                                            wbMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(j).Value = cell_location.EntireColumn.Value
                                            j = j + 1
                    
                                            Set cell_location = .FindNext(cell_location)                               
                    
                                        Loop While Not cell_location Is Nothing And cell_location.Address <> cell_address
                
                                End If
                        End With
                        Set cell_location = Nothing
                      
                If i = total_values Then Exit For
                Next i
            Next
                
    myfilname = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: try without fileformat on line `myfilname = Dir(fldrpath & "*.xls*")`  `myfilname = Dir(fldrpath)`

Comment: Note that if you declare `Dim i, j As Integer` only `j` is of type `Integer` but `i` is of type `Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or it is `Variant` by default. Also those need to be `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim i As Long, j As Long`.

Comment: @Tomasz: I tried it and still gives the same error at the same line "Set wbSlave = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myfilname)"

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I changed both i and j variables to Long and I am still getting the same error

Comment: @AnchalSondhi That was just a note, that this was wrong too. That's not the solution to the issue. The solution is in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dir function returns only the matching filename - no path. Then if you try to open it and you are currently not in a correct folder, you get this error.

Set a watch to the variable `myfilname` or just add `Debug.Print myfilname` and you see it right away.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: I put Debug.Print myfilname and it is printing the all the filenames in the folder correctly but still giving the same error.

I am not able to figure out and solve why the moment "Set wbSlave = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myfilname)" line is triggered it gives me that error for missing or moved file.

Please help!!

Comment: @AnchalSondhi `Workbooks.Open` needs a **path** and a filename, but `myfilname` is only a filename **without path**. You need to add the path before `myfilname`: `Workbooks.Open(filename:=fldrpath & myfilname)`. Excel cannot know which folder the file is unless you tell it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Shazam!! It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton for this help. Really appreciate it!!